# How to integrate $\int \frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x}dx$?

Tags: integration

Ok! So I tried putting $x=a\cos(t)$ and my answer came out as $a\sin(t)-a\log{(\sec(t)+\tan(t))}$. But the answer given is $(a^2-x^2)+a\frac{\log{(\sqrt{a-(a^2-x^2)})}}{x}$. I'd like to know where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: How can we answer without knowing what you did ???

Comment: If you compute an indefinite integral using u-substitution, you must substitute back after you have found the anti-derivative of the substituted integrand.

Comment: Hint: rewrite the integral as $\int \frac{\sqrt{a^2(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})}}{x}dx$ and take $\displaystyle \frac{x}{a}=\sin{t}$ So this implies $$a dx=\cos{t}dt\implies \int \frac{\sqrt{a^2(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})}}{x}dx=\int \frac{\sqrt{a^2(1-\sin{t}^2)}}{\sin{t}}\cos{t}dt=\int \frac{\sqrt{a^2}\cos{t}}{\sin{t}}\cos{t}dt$$

Comment: ok! thanks I will try!

Comment: @YvesDaoust Of course we can, some just choose not to.

Comment: @Tavish: you don't understand. The OP is asking "where am I going wrong ?" I'd be curious to know how you answer this. Crystal ball ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949882/evaluate-int-fracx3-sqrt81x2-16dx-using-trigonometric-substitution and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662305/trig-substitution

Comment: @YvesDaoust Nope. They mentioned the substitution they used, so if someone gives a step-by-step solution using that route, they will know where they went wrong. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: rewrite the integral as $\displaystyle\int \frac{\sqrt{a^2(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})}}{x}dx$ and take $\displaystyle \frac{x}{a}=\sin{t}$.

So this implies that: $$dx=\cos{t}dt\implies \int \frac{\sqrt{a^2(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})}}{x}dx=\int \frac{\sqrt{a^2(1-(\sin{t})^2)}}{\sin{t}}\cos{t}dt=\int \frac{\sqrt{a^2}\cos{(t)}}{\sin{(t)}}\cos{(t)}dt=\int \sqrt{a^2}\cot{(t)}\cos{(t)}dt$$
Now rewriting $\cos{(t)}\cot{(t)}$ as $\csc{(t)}-\sin{(t)}$ we have:
$$\sqrt{a^2}\Big(-\int \sin{(t)}dt+\int \csc{(t)}dt\Big)=\sqrt{a^2}\Big(-\cos{t}-\log{(\cot(t) + \csc(t))}\Big) $$
Now $t=\arcsin{\frac{x}{a}}\implies a\Big(-\cos{(\arcsin{\frac{x}{a}})}-\log{(\cot(\arcsin{\frac{x}{a}}) + \csc(\arcsin{\frac{x}{a}}))}\Big) $.

Since  $\cos(\arcsin{\frac{x}{a}})=\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}$ and $\cot(\arcsin{\frac{x}{a}})=\sqrt{-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}{\frac{x}{a}}$ and $\csc(\arcsin{(\frac{x}{a}}))=\frac{1}{\frac{x}{a}}$, it remains:
$$\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-a\log\Bigg({\frac{a\big(\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}+1\big)}{x}}\Bigg)+c$$

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and answering! Appreciate it.