# Equality between logarithms coming out from an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, logarithms

I have looked at this question and to the answer [Integral to solve](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4053521/867100) to solve the integral asked.
In the answer it is stated that the result is
$$\text{something}\,-|a|\ln{\Bigg(\frac{|a|(\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}+1)}{x}}\Bigg)$$
But really I have computed by hand the integral and my result is:
$$\text{something}\,+\frac{|a|}{2}\ln\Bigg({\frac{\bigg|1-\sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg)^2}\bigg|}{\bigg|1+\sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg)^2}\bigg|}}\Bigg)$$
I want to prove that the two results are equal. So:
$$\frac{|a|}{2}\ln\Bigg({\frac{\bigg|1-\sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg)^2}\bigg|}{\bigg|1+\sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg)^2}\bigg|}}\Bigg)=-\frac{|a|}{2}\ln\Bigg({\frac{\bigg|1+\sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg)^2}\bigg|}{\bigg|1-\sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg)^2}\bigg|}}\Bigg)=$$ $$-\frac{|a|}{2}\ln\Bigg({\frac{\bigg(1+\sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg)^2}\bigg)^2}{\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}\Bigg)=-|a|\ln\Bigg({\frac{|a|\Big(1+\sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg)^2}\Big)}{x}}\Bigg)$$
$\textbf{1}$Do you think my iea is correct?
$\textbf{2.}$ Moreover in the answer [Integral to solve](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4053521/867100) it is stated the result with $a$ and not with $|a|$ but I think that the absolute value is necessary since $a$ comes out from the $\sqrt{a^2}$, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
$$\frac{|1+a|}{|1-a|}=\frac{(1+a)^2}{|1-a||1+a|}=\frac{(1+a)^2}{|(1+a)(1-a)|}=\frac{(1+a)^2}{|1-a^2|}$$

Comment: Also $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$, yes.

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming my ideas!