# Integral of $\int \frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x} \, dx$ and the result of WolframAlpha

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

In solving the integral $\int \frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x} \, dx$ I have found out by hand thet the result is $$|a|\sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg)^2}+\frac{|a|}{2}\ln\Bigg({\frac{\bigg|1-\sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg)^2}\bigg|}{\bigg|1+\sqrt{1-\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg)^2}\bigg|}}\Bigg)+c=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-|a|\ln{\Bigg(\frac{|a|\big(\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}+1\big)}{|x|}}\Bigg)+c$$
But in order to check my result I have write the integral on wolfram and it tells me that is:
$$\sqrt{(a^2 - x^2)} - a \tanh^{-1}{(\frac{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}{a}}) \,\,\,\,(*)$$
[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20sqrt%28a%5E2-x%5E2%29%2Fx)

I don't know if really my result and $(*)$ are equivalent. Can you help me?

Comment: Your first step should probably be to pick an $a$ and plot both expressions. If they look nothing alike, something must be wrong.

Comment: Could you edit in how you calculated your result?

Comment: The Wolfram Alpha output is **not** what you wrote.  It is not $\arctan$ but instead the inverse **hyperbolic** tangent, $\tanh^{-1}$.

Comment: @J.G. I have looked at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4053521/914360, but considering that $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$, so my result apart from this absolute value looks the same...but wolfram alpha states something that I dont' know if it is equal

Comment: @heropup yes thanks! I have corrected

Comment: You could avoid the complexity of dragging $a$s with you everywhere if you start by substituting $t=x/a$.

Comment: Actually, there's a feature available at https://www.integral-calculator.com/ which not only solves the integral but also tells you if your antiderivative is correct or not if you choose to verify your answer.

Comment: @AnkitSaha wonderful! I will use it in future! Very thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\operatorname{artanh}u=\tfrac12\ln\tfrac{1+u}{1-u}$, Wolfram Alpha's formula is $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-\tfrac12a\ln\tfrac{a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}+c$, in agreement with your calculation.

Comment: Ok very thanks! Do you think that the absolute value on $a$ is necessary?

Comment: @Sisi If you work with logarithms, yes; if you work with hyperbolic arctangents, it makes no difference because $\operatorname{artanh}$ is odd.

Comment: Ok very thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The equivalence arises from an elementary hyperbolic trigonometric identity.  Recall
$$y = \tanh x = \frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x} = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}},$$ hence solving this equation for $x$ yields $$x = \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{1+y}{1-y} = \tanh^{-1} y.$$ This is actually what you wrote in your first step when simplifying your antiderivative, with the choice $$y = \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}{a}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!